# accessing an element in <html> inside <html> with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

there is this website with a weird [html body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQco.jpg), i did manage to open the 2nd html code in a new tab but its not what i want unfortunately i am trying to auto click it with selenium but it seems to be inaccessible i've tried the following selectors:

```
vidstream = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, value='html')[1]
# error: list index out of range!
```

```
vidstream = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value='._reload')
# error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._reload"}
```

```
vidstream = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.fullpage.vidplay._reload')
# erroe: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".fullpage.vidplay._reload"}
```

and many other possibilities but with out any luck,
any work around is welcome, thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQco.jpg)

Comment: What you have basically is an `iframe`. You have to first switch to iframe, and then access the element

Comment: what do you mean by "switch to ifream"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (assuming you have only 1 iframe, or the occurrence in question is the first iframe):

iframe is a subset of the main DOM. It is not necessarily that all websites uses this, but some do; in such case, you first need to switch your selenium pointer to the iframe first, and when the pointer is in iframe, then access the elements inside the iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fullpage video _reload") # pls check if I have written the class name correctly.
```

And then to switch back to parent DOM:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Note: I do not know if pointer is the right term, but I thought it helps in making you understand in a colloquial tongue.

Comment: If you still have issues, please post the entire HMTL in code format. Image format does not help debugging. It is all the better if you post the website url, if it is ok to share it in public here